# Python tkinter: Make the output appear in a text box on GUI not in the shell

Tags: python, textbox, tkinter, output

I have a tkinter menu that lets the user choose some functions. I would like if the output of that functions was presented on a texbox in Tkinter instead of the Shell. Im very unexperienced with Tkinter. I don´t have any ideia how to do it..

Some of the functions require inputs of the user, is it possible for the user to input directly from Tkinter Gui?

The code for the menu of the program:

the functions: situacaocorrente(), findfuncionario(), verhistorico() are not presented here.

**CODE**

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu, Label, Text
import sys



class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent
        self.output = Text(self)
        self.output.pack()
        sys.stdout = self
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("High Flex")


        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)

        fileMenu.add_command(label="Procurar funcionario", command=self.procurarfuncionario)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Ver Historico", command=self.historico)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Verificar Onde se encontram os funcionarios", command=self.funcionariosturno)

        fileMenu.add_command(label="Sair", command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="INICIAR", menu=fileMenu)

    def funcionariosturno(self):
        situacaocorrente()

    def procurarfuncionario(self):

        findfuncionario()

    def historico (self):
        verhistorico()


    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

    def write(self, txt):
        self.output.insert(END,str(txt))




def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example(root)


    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net). It probably has what you need in it, and even if not, it will provide you with some good examples of using Tkinter.

Comment: FYI... EasyGUI was officially declared dead earlier this year.  It may be still useful, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Entry()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) to get user input. See more on: [An Introduction to Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook)

I don't know what functions output you try to put in `self.output` - from external program in shell or from python function.

`sys.stdout = self` works only with Python functions like `print`